# How to implement the simple Rect.insersects(Rect one, Rect two) method?

Tags: android, canvas, boolean, collision

I have read the android spill on this method tons of times and it isn't ringing any bells. Bellow is a part of my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);

          boolean CollisionTest;

          Rect jSquare = new Rect();
          Rect mSquare = new Rect();

          jSquare.set(0,500,600,400);
              mSquare.set(0, 500,700, 100);

    canvas.drawRect(mSquare, Some Color..);
        canvas.drawRect(jSquare, Some Color...);

  CollisionTest = Rect.intersects(jSquare, mSquare);

  if (ColisionTest==true){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`set`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public void set (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

> Set the rectangle's coordinates to the specified values. Note: no range checking is performed, so it is up to the caller to ensure that left <= right and top <= bottom.

500 > 100

Comment: DUDE! THANKS SO FREAKING MUCH!!! I spent 8 hours trying to figure this out i cant believe that was the prob.... thanks so much seriously